# How to use swagger file locally?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Hi I have a swagger file written for my API and I could not test the paths of my API since I am getting: `ERROR Server not found or an error occurred` because my paths are all localhost, so how can i use swagger locally? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is using the building from source way in [swagger-editor](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are developing within Visual studio click the green play looking button to build & run your solution , a browser should now pop up. ignore whatever it comes up with and type localhost/swagger and it should provide you with the interface. Let me know what happens or if you require any assistance